# How to handle URL with special characters present in password in Postman?

Tags: postman, web-api-testing

I have the following format in URL.

```
http://username:password@test.nabin.com/some/url
```

Here password is something like **qDTA*$X)ME/74**. When I directly use this password in URL, then the postman does not respond. How should I proceed testing this url?

(In the image the response container is plain white without any error. This indicates, the API was never hit)
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can manually encode parts of the URL within the application. These are the docs from version 6.

https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/requests/#sending-parameters

Under the URL section:

“Note: Parameters you enter in the URL bar or in the data editor will not automatically be URL-encoded. Right click a piece of selected text, and select “EncodeURIComponent” to manually encode the parameter value.”

Comment: This link is dead.

Comment: Fixed now @Martijn :)

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, I will share how I handled this. I used two lines of python script for quoting the password and using the output in the postman.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
>>> quote_plus('qDTA*$X)ME/74')
'qDTA%2A%24X%29ME%2F74'
```

Then I simply used this quoted password to construct the following new URL:

```
http://username:qDTA%2A%24X%29ME%2F74@test.nabin.com/some/url
```

Hopefully someone comes here and answers how we should do it properly.

Comment: In the newer versions of Postman you can select a part of the text in the URL, right click and get an option to encode that value.

Comment: For a very long time - The version in that image is years old. Grab the native client app for your OS - packed full of features that you wouldn’t ever see in the one you have.