# postman could not handle unicode characters in url for routing

Tags: unicode, wso2, postman, content-type, wso2-esb

I have defined an *API Resource* in *WSO2 ESB* like this with **GET** method:

```
/sms/{username}/{password}/{src}/{destination}/{body}
```

Now if I invoke my API through a standard browser like chrome or firefox it works fine and I get response code **ok 200**

```
127.x.x.x:8280/sms/username/password/123123123/456456456/سلام
```

But I can not invoke this API through **Postman** and it returns **Not-Found 404**. If I replace **'سلام'** with a standard **ascii** string like **'hello'** it works fine and it returns code **ok 200**:

```
127.x.x.x:8280/sms/username/password/123123123/456456456/hello
```

I tried numerous **Content-Type**s in **Headers** tab of *postman* including this but it didn't work:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I also monitored network requests with **fiddler**. Standard browser send request with this parameters:

> Connection: keep-alive Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1 User-Agent:
>   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,
>   like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

And *Postman* send request with this parameters:

> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 cache-control: no-cache
>   Postman-Token: 5ccc574f-54d2-4c5b-ac72-b0f5f5a8e0be User-Agent:
>   PostmanRuntime/7.3.0 Accept: */*
>   accept-encoding: gzip, deflate Connection: keep-alive

I use *postman* **v6.4.4**

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49964318/9624430

Comment: @senthalan Yes, it worked, `سلام` should be encoded to `%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85` could you please write down your comment as an answer?  So I can check it as correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manually encode parts of the URL.

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49964318/9624430

Answer (score 0):

I tried this issue with **WSO2 ESB 5.0.0**. It works for me as you expected through **postman**.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test-api" context="/test">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/value/{val1}">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full">
            <property name="test" expression="get-property('uri.var.val1')"/>
         </log>
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{ "test": "$1"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('uri.var.val1')"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Request: [http://localhost:8280/test/value/سلام](http://localhost:8280/test/value/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85)

Response:

```
{
    "test": "سلام"
}
```

Try with WSO2 ESB 5.0.0.

Comment: Thanks but we are using WSO2 ESB 6.4. We prefer to don't maintain multiple versions of WSO2. It would be nice if someone could confirm that it is a known issue with v6.4.