# Swagger API Special character issue

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am new in swagger and want to deploy an API which is having query string. This is the API I am getting encoded URL after passing the parameter in the GET method.

API URL with Parameter should be:-

```
baseurl/v1/auth/getOTP?email=somename@email.com
```

but I am getting something like:-

```
baseurl/v1/auth/getOTP?email=somename%40email.com
```

what I have tried is:-

```
    "/auth/getOTP": {
  "get": {
    "tags": [
      "pet"
    ],
    "summary": "",
    "description": "",
    "operationId": "findPetsByStatus",
    "produces": [
      "application/json",
      "application/xml"
    ],
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "email",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
      }
    ],
    "responses": {
      "200": {
        "description": "successful operation",
        "schema": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/Pet"
          }
        }
      },
      "400": {
        "description": "Invalid value"
      }
    },
    "security": [
      {
        "petstore_auth": [
          "write:pets",
          "read:pets"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: add this property `allowReserved: true` in your parameters and for more details https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/

Comment: @turivishal: where should I add this property, 

 "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "email",
        "in": "path",
        "description": "",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "allowReserved":true
      }

its also not working

Comment: Yes, You can add in specific `parameters` object together with name, in, type properties

Comment: it's not working

Answer (score 1):

**Swagger OpenAPI has Specified:** in this GitHub [Issue-1840](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/1840), It is specifically disallowed on `in: path` parameters for the same reason they don't allow optional path parameters, e.g. `{/foo}` By having variable path segments it become difficult to resolve a URL to an operation.

If you want to use some kind of hack then follow this GitHub [Issue-230](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/230).

If you really needed then Its support in `in: query` parameters, as below,

The `allowReserved` keyword specifies whether the reserved characters `:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=` in parameter values are allowed to be sent as they are, or should be percent-encoded. By default, `allowReserved` is `false`, and reserved characters are percent-encoded.

Here you need to set it to `true`,

```
"parameters": [
    {
        "name": "email",
        "in": "query",
        "description": "",
        "required": true,
        "type": "string",
        "allowReserved": true
    }
],
```

Look at the Example [Swagger Describing Parameters](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/)
and For more details follow [Swagger Serialization](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/).

Comment: I have tried this, but it's working for swagger-ui only not for any other clients. Any ideas?

Comment: What are other clients?

Comment: I am not sure but there will be some settings in postman see [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43611238/url-encode-postman-variable), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49961858/how-to-handle-url-with-special-characters-present-in-password-in-postman/49964318#49964318)